# Download instructions for parsing HTML data

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, parsing

I'm developing an iPhone app that mainly logs in to third party websites and parses the HTML data for specific information, like dates and times etc.

However, this is obviously easily broken if the websites update their HTML template even the slightest.

I don't want the app to break, and if it does - I don't want to send in an update to apple every time.

I need an easy smart way for my app to download "instructions" on how to parse a website, from my own server. That way, if the HTML changes; I can just update the instructions on my server instead of sending out a whole new app update to apple.

I'm currently using XPath to find data with the library TFHpple, but also by reaching the TFHppleElements children in objective c.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, the even smarter way is probably to not just have your server send 'instructions' on how to parse the website, but have your server do the entire scraping itself and act as a 'middleware'. Your server can do the web scraping, convert the content into JSON/XML/whatever, and then your devices can request it. If the website changes, you just have to update the server, and you can offload the parsing from device to the server (which could, depending on the content you're scraping, significantly reduce load on the site being scraped).

Comment: This is not an option, as the user logs in to the websites using their login credentials, and neither the user nor the websites wants me to handle and store their login details. The login and parsing needs to be done at the client

Answer (score 0):

**Parsing of HTML**

How brilliant is your code to parse any website that includes HTML, you need to be updated every moment of time. And even if you are all foolproof done with the website. 
The problem arises how to parse website that contains HTML.

Possibly you would use NSRegularExpression, NSPredicate etc to use.

A big discussion here : [Never Parse HTML using RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 0):

You can look instructions in this website :

[The Best XMLParser pour your iPhone Project](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project)